# How to simplify correlated subquery in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hiveql

I have query in sql server which I want to simplify so that it can be Hive compatible. 
This is the query written in SQL format

```
SELECT session_id, 
       Substring ((SELECT ( ';' + tag_name ) 
               FROM   session_tag st2 
               WHERE  st2.session_id = st.session_id 
               FOR xml path ( '' )), 2, 1000) AS tags 
FROM   session_tag 
GROUP  BY session_id;
```

This is the result of this query

[image]

Once again I don't want to pass **select query** inside the **substring** function.

So I tried to simplify these query to get the same result the first query shows nothing and second one throws an error that **subquery returned more than one result**.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(';'+tag_name,2,1000) as tag from session_tag st1 
where st1.session_id = (select st2.session_id from session_tag st2 where st1.session_id = st2.session_id for xml path (''))
```

and

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(';'+tag_name,2,1000) as tag from session_tag st1 
where st1.session_id = (select st2.session_id from session_tag st2 where st1.session_id = st2.session_id) for xml path('')
```

Comment: I don't know Hive, at all, but I would guess that it's method of generating a CSV string is not the same as SQL Server.  So maybe you should start with your Hive query instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right now I am only trying to simplify the query in sql server format.

Comment: The XML path trick to generate CSV in SQL Server needs a subquery AFAIK.  And you would also need to wrap in `SUBSTRING` if you only want the first 1000 characters.  Later versions of SQL Server have a function called `STRING_AGG`; this doesn't require a formal subquery.

Comment: In pre 2017 version, this is about as simple as can be for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. The simplified version of this query is

```
SELECT session_id, Substring(d.tagList,2,1000) as tag from (
select distinct session_id from session_tag) a
cross apply 
(
    select ';'+tag_name from session_tag as b
    where a.session_id = b.session_id for xml path ('')
) d (tagList)
```

Comment: It's good you found a solution that's worked for you. Even better you posted it. I don't see how this query is simpler then the query in the question, but hey, if it works...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have to translate the query for the Hive, and unfortunately hive only supports top level subqueries. Even this is also not the simplified version but it works perfectly in hive.

Comment: I see. well, perhaps simplified is just the wrong term to use :-)